# How do I fix long run time on eight puzzle solver? (Python)

Tags: python, runtime

I have written the following code that enables a user to automatically create an eight puzzle. It then allows them to solve it themselves or have it solved automatically using A* search.
   The problem is when the automatic solver is challenged with shuffles of 10 or more it occasionally continues on for a long time and then fails. I am not sure why it is unable to solve the puzzle. 
Thanks

```
import random
import copy
grid2=[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '-']]
def menu():
        global choice
        print("If you would like to play the game, enter 1.")
        print("If you would like to automatically solve a puzzle, enter 2.")
        print("If you would like to quit the game, enter 3.")
        choice = input("Enter your choice here ---> ")
        while choice not in ("1","2","3"):
                print ("Please only enter the numbers 1,2 or 3.")
                choice = input("Enter your choice here ---> ")
        if choice=="1" or choice=="2":
                set_shuffle()
        elif choice=="3":
                quit

def set_shuffle():
        global shuffle
        shuffle = int(0)
        while shuffle<1:
                print("Please only enter positive integers.")
                while True:
                        try:
                                shuffle = input("How many times would you like the puzzle to be shuffled?")
                                shuffle = int(shuffle)
                                break
                        except ValueError:
                                print("Please only enter positive integers.")
        grid_creater()

def grid_creater():
        global pos
        global grid
        grid=[]
        for x in range(3):
                grid.append([" "]*3)
        for x in range(8):
                if x<3:
                        grid[0][x]=str(x+1)
                elif x<6:
                        grid[1][x-3]=str(x+1)
                else:
                        grid[2][x-6]=str(x+1)
        grid[2][2]="-"
        pos=[2,2]
        shuffle_grid()

def shuffle_grid():
        global shuffle
        for z in range(shuffle):
                moves=[]
                if pos[0]==0:
                        moves +=[4]
                elif pos[0]==1:
                        moves +=[3,4]
                else:
                        moves +=[3]
                if pos[1]==0:
                        moves +=[1]
                elif pos[1]==1:
                        moves +=[1,2]
                else:
                        moves +=[2]       
                move=moves[random.randint(0,len(moves)-1)]
                x=0
                y=0
                if move==1:
                        x=1
                elif move==2:
                        x=-1
                elif move==3:
                        y=-1
                elif move==4:
                        y=1
                reserve = grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]
                grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = grid[pos[0]+y][pos[1]+x]
                grid[pos[0]+y][pos[1]+x]=reserve
                pos[0]+=y
                pos[1]+=x
        print_grid(grid)

def print_grid(grid):
        for row in grid:
                print ("  ".join(row))
        if choice=="1":
                player_move()
        elif choice=="2":
                auto_sort()

def player_move():
        print(grid)
        num_moves=0
        while grid != grid2:
                num_moves+=1
                moves=[]
                if pos[0]==0:
                        moves +=[4]
                elif pos[0]==1:
                        moves +=[3,4]
                else:
                        moves +=[3]
                if pos[1]==0:
                        moves +=[1]
                elif pos[1]==1:
                        moves +=[1,2]
                else:
                        moves +=[2]
                print("If you would like to move right, enter 1.")
                print("If you would like to move left, enter 2.")
                print("If you would like to move up, enter 3.")
                print("If you would like to move down, enter 4.")
                pm = int(input("Enter your choice here ---> "))
                while pm not in moves:
                        print ("This is an invalid move, please pick another.")
                        pm = int(input("Enter your choice here ---> "))
                x=0
                y=0
                if pm==1:
                        x=1
                elif pm==2:
                        x=-1
                elif pm==3:
                        y=-1
                elif pm==4:
                        y=1
                reserve = grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]
                grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = grid[pos[0]+y][pos[1]+x]
                grid[pos[0]+y][pos[1]+x]=reserve
                pos[0]+=y
                pos[1]+=x
                for row in grid:
                        print ("  ".join(row))
        print("Completed in",num_moves,"moves.\n")
        menu()

def auto_sort():
        num_moves=0
        open_value=[]
        open_grid=[]
        close_grid=[]
        hvalue=0
        for a in range(3):
                for b in range(3):
                        if grid[a][b] != grid2[a][b]:
                                hvalue+=1
        open_value.append(hvalue)
        open_grid.append(grid)
        x=open_value.index(min(open_value))
        current_node=open_grid[x]
        while current_node != grid2:
                num_moves+=1
                for f in range(0,3):
                        if '-' in current_node[f]:
                                c_point=[f,current_node[f].index('-')]
                moves=[]
                child_nodes=[]
                if c_point[0]==0:
                        moves +=[4]
                elif c_point[0]==1:
                        moves +=[3,4]
                else:
                        moves +=[3]
                if c_point[1]==0:
                        moves +=[1]
                elif c_point[1]==1:
                        moves +=[1,2]
                else:
                        moves +=[2]
                for k in range(1,5):
                        new_node=[]
                        y=0
                        x=0
                        if k in moves:
                                if k==1:
                                        x=1
                                elif k==2:
                                        x=-1
                                elif k==3:
                                        y=-1
                                elif k==4:
                                        y=1
                                new_node=copy.deepcopy(current_node)
                                reserve = new_node[c_point[0]][c_point[1]]
                                new_node[c_point[0]][c_point[1]] = new_node[c_point[0]+y][c_point[1]+x]
                                new_node[c_point[0]+y][c_point[1]+x]=reserve
                                if new_node in open_grid or new_node in close_grid:
                                        new_node=[]
                                else:
                                        child_nodes.append(new_node)
                for p in range(len(child_nodes)):
                        hvalue=0
                        for a in range(3):
                                for b in range(3):
                                        if child_nodes[p][a][b] != grid2[a][b]:
                                                hvalue+=1
                        open_value.append(hvalue)
                        open_grid.append(child_nodes[p])
                close_grid.append(current_node)
                open_value.pop(x)
                open_grid.pop(x)
                x=open_value.index(min(open_value))
                current_node=open_grid[x]
                for row in current_node:
                        print ("  ".join(row))
        print("Completed in",num_moves,"moves.\n")
        menu()

menu()
```

Comment: Joe are you sure the case is solvable? As far as I remember, there are two sets of states in 8-puzzle problem that you cannot get from one to the other one. I order to avoid unsolvable state, you can randomly shuffle from the actual solution. A* should be able to solve the problem in less than 20 steps if the correct heuristic is used.

Comment: I believe that I am shuffling from the original position. However I may need to use a different heuristic.